# How to obtain the width of a column within the APA document class?

Tags: columns, apa-style, tabularx, width

I am using the APA document class. My document has some tables:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{This is the title}
\author{This is the author}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    This is some text so that you can see how wide each of the columns is in the document.

    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        1 & 2 \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, the width is too wide and does not match the column width. I tried replacing `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`, but this did not work either.

- How can I set the table to match the width of the columns in the APA document class?

Comment: I get the correct width both with `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth`, which is what you should use when the document is in two column format.

Comment: With the code above, changed to `\columnwidth`, it compiles with a table which spans the two columns.

Comment: The example document is in *one column* format. If you add `twocolum` to the document class options and use `\columnwidth`, the result is as expected.

Comment: I found that `\maketitle` sets the document to two column format. I tried adding `\columnwidth` and the document class option, but it still compiles with a table which does not fit the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APA class redefines `\tabular` in a way that thoroughly confuses `tabularx`.

Here's a workaround: in the `apatabularx` we restore the original meanings of `\tabular` and `\endtabular`.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\title{This is the title}
\author{This is the author}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{apatabularx}
  {\let\tabular\old@tabular\let\endtabular\orig@endtabular\tabularx}
  {\endtabularx}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\medskip

\noindent\begin{apatabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|}
This is some text so that you can see how wide each of the columns is in the document.
&
This is some text so that you can see how wide each of the columns is in the document.
\\
\end{apatabularx}

\medskip

\lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```