# apa6[jou]: How to use \columnwidth in threeparttable?

Tags: apa6, column-width

I am using the apa6 class. My document has some instances of `threeparttable`. I can not manage to use `\columnwidth` to define the tables to match the column-width of my two column article.

I have read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64047/how-to-obtain-the-width-of-a-column-within-the-apa-document-class) that the APA class redefines `\tabular` which seems to be the reason for this problem.

Unfortunately I can not transfer the answer to my case of a `threeparttable`.

I am using another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) to define fix widths for centered columns. But the problem also occurs when I use p{...\columnwidth}.

In the figure environment everything is alright.

The help of a more experienced LaTeX user would be highly appreciated!

My document:

```
\documentclass[jou, keeplastbox]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%TODO: ensure table width == columnwidth
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{Susurration}
\affiliation{Void}

\abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa6} \LaTeX\
    class to format the document in compliance with the 6th Edition of
    the American Psychological Assocation's \textit{Publication Manual.}
    The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}
\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% this looks good but the defintion of widths is not very handy
% furthermore these width definitions seem to be sensitive to table content
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Looks good but width definitions are bad}
        \label{tab:stimuli_domain}
        \begin{tabular}{C{0.15\columnwidth}C{0.15\columnwidth}C{0.25\columnwidth}C{0.25\columnwidth}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cues}        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Stimuli} \\
            Number\tabfnm{a}    & Validity  & A & B \\
            \midrule
            1       & 0.8       & 1         & 0 \\
            2       & 0.6       & 0         & 0 \\
            3       & 0.75      & 1         & 1 \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            {\small
                \textit{Note.}  Column 3 and Column 4 represent stimuli by assigning binary variables as given in equation \ref{eq:feature_def}.
            }
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

% I would like to have this code to make span the table the whole column
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Looks bad but should look nice}
        \label{tab:stimuli_domain_}
        \begin{tabular}{C{0.2\columnwidth}C{0.2\columnwidth}C{0.4\columnwidth}C{0.4\columnwidth}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cues}        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Stimuli} \\
            Number\tabfnm{a}    & Validity  & A & B \\
            \midrule
            1       & 0.8       & 1         & 0 \\
            2       & 0.6       & 0         & 0 \\
            3       & 0.75      & 1         & 1 \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            {\small
                \textit{Note.}  Column 3 and Column 4 represent stimuli by assigning binary variables as given in equation \ref{eq:feature_def}.
            }
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the `tabularx` package.

```
\documentclass[jou, keeplastbox]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%TODO: ensure table width == columnwidth
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{Susurration}
\affiliation{Void}

\abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa6} \LaTeX\
    class to format the document in compliance with the 6th Edition of
    the American Psychological Assocation's \textit{Publication Manual.}
    The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}
\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% this looks good but the defintion of widths is not very handy
% furthermore these width definitions seem to be sensitive to table content
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{tabularx environment solves the problem}
        \label{tab:stimuli_domain}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{p{0.2\columnwidth}p{0.2\columnwidth}p{0.3\columnwidth}p{0.3\columnwidth}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cues}        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Stimuli} \\
            Number\tabfnm{a}    & Validity  & A & B \\
            \midrule
            1       & 0.8       & 1         & 0 \\
            2       & 0.6       & 0         & 0 \\
            3       & 0.75      & 1         & 1 \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            {\small
                \textit{Note.}  Column 3 and Column 4 represent stimuli by assigning binary variables as given in equation \ref{eq:feature_def}.
            }
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-2]

% I would like to have this code to make span the table the whole column
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{tabularx environment solves the problem}
        \label{tab:stimuli_domain_}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{p{0.2\columnwidth}p{0.2\columnwidth}p{0.3\columnwidth}p{0.3\columnwidth}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cues}        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Stimuli} \\
            Number\tabfnm{a}    & Validity  & A & B \\
            \midrule
            1       & 0.8       & 1         & 0 \\
            2       & 0.6       & 0         & 0 \\
            3       & 0.75      & 1         & 1 \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            {\small
                \textit{Note.}  Column 3 and Column 4 represent stimuli by assigning binary variables as given in equation \ref{eq:feature_def}.
            }
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```